# Expo: Receive remote-notifications on iOS when the app is in the foreground

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am sending remote notifications to my app on iOS (content-available: 1). When my app is in the background, Expo triggers the execution of the notification task and I can receive the notification. But when my app is running (i.e. in foreground) and I send a remote notification (content-available: 1), Expo neither calls the registered task nor the Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener callback for the notification.

If I send a regular alert notification when my app is in the foreground, the callback (Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener) is called as expected.

I also have the handler (Notifications.setNotificationHandler) registered which is called when an alert notification is received but never gets called when a remote-notification is receive (content-available: 1).

I think I am missing something basic here.

I am trying to use the remote notifications to communicate the progress of a long running action and wanted to avoid the client polling the server.

Is there a way to get a callback when a remote-notification is delivered and my app is in the foreground?

Thanks for the help.